# detect if H2O instance is already running in R

Tags: r, jvm, h2o

This relates to the h2o package in R. I'm working with multiple jobs running in parallel, some may come in later than others. Is it possible to detect whether a h2o instance already exists and make a connection to that instance.

I see that if I know an instance is already running, i just do `h2o.init(startH2O=FALSE)`, but what if I don't know that?

Answer (score 2):

Just do `h2o.init(startH2O=FALSE)` and if it fails you know it wasn't running.

(Alternatively, you could make your own curl request to port 54321, and see if there is a reply.)

When you say "multiple jobs running in parallel", do you mean one instance of H2O, and it is making 2+ models at the same time? Or do you mean you are running 2+ instances of H2O, on a single machine, on different ports? If the latter, give the port number of interest to your `h2o.init()` call (but make sure you use the most recent version, the `port` arg was ignored until Nov 18th 2016: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/401 )

Comment: I'd like to run two or more R scripts concurrently and independently, each using some functionality of h2o, e.g. reading/writing a dataset to and from server, training two separate, unrelated models. I'm aware of `startH2O=FALSE` but it seems odd to have to check failure to know whether an instance is running.  But thks.

Comment: @horaceT For *that* use case I'd just do `h2o.init()`: the first script that runs will start H2O for you, and the second will automatically use the running instance.  (To be precise `h2o.init(nthreads=-1, max_mem_size = "4g")`, and make sure your scripts all use the same command; alternatively start it from the commandline in advance.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to just check the status without getting an error or exiting the script, you can use `trycatch` to achieve it.

```
assign("is_h2o_running", T, .GlobalEnv)

tryCatch(
    
    expr = {
        h2o.init(startH2O=FALSE)
    },
    error = function(e){ 
        print(e)
        assign("is_h2o_running", F, .GlobalEnv)
    },
    warning = function(w){
        print(w)
    }
)

print(paste0("Is H2O running : ", is_h2o_running))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you see if you try `h2o.init(start_h2o=False)` in Python.
"Warning: if you don't want to start local H2O server, then use of `h2o.connect()`
 is preferred."